# Relative Pathing in jQuery Load function in UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-load, showmodaldialog

I'm using the .load() function to load an .aspx page into my jQuery UI Dialog, which works fine.  The issue is that the page being loaded is in a different directory than what the dialog open call is coming from and when i try to hit my 'submit' button from that newly loaded page it can't find the 'search.aspx' path because it's looking in the original path.

Basically:

ucEasyFill.ascx contains the div declaration, and the link to open the modal popup. this is located in the forms/UserControls/ folder;

```
<div id="modalSearchWindow" style="display:none;" class="MODAL_SEARCH_WINDOW"></div> 

<img id="imgClearClient" src="images\clear.png" class="efIMG" />Clear </a><a href="#" id="lnkFindClient" name="lnkFindClient" onclick="javascript: MODAL_SEARCH_WINDOW.dialog('open');"><img id="imgSearchMag" src="/applications/images/search_mag.gif" class="efIMG" />Find</a>
```

ucEasyFill.js contains the dialog declaration within the document.ready function in forms/scripts/ folder;

```
MODAL_SEARCH_WINDOW = $("#modalSearchWindow").load('EasyFill/Search.aspx').dialog({
    position: "center",
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    autoResize: true,
    draggable: true,
    modal: true,
    width: 580,
    height: 450,
    dialogClass: "MODAL_SEARCH_WINDOW",
    closeOnEscape: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $('.MODAL_SEARCH_WINDOW .ui-dialog-titlebar').each(function () {
            $(this).css("display", "none");
        });
    }
});
```

When 'Search' is clicked on `forms/EasyFill/Search.aspx` page i receive the 404 error of;

```
    POST http://localhost/applications/forms/Search.aspx 404 (Not Found)
```

which makes sense to me since the dialog is being loaded from the `/forms/` directory and not from the `forms/easyfill/` directory.  Really my question is how do i get around this?  I am only trying to do this because of the new deprecation of `showModalDialog()` in Chrome 37

Comment: `/EasyFill/Search.aspx` is an absolute path, not a relative path. It should be loaded from `http://localhost/EasyFill/Search.aspx`. Did you make a copying mistake?

Comment: If you have `EasyFill/Search.aspx` it should look for `forms/EasyFill/Search.aspx`. Relative paths are interpreted relative to the directory of the page making the reference. So this should work.

Comment: The error you're getting would only happen if you had `.load('Search.aspx')`.

Comment: i've done it using the 'EasyFill/Search.aspx' as well as with the leading '/' and have tried hard-coding via localhost as 'http://localhost/applications/forms/easyfill/search.aspx' but i still receive the same error, wasn't sure if it's just how jQuery dialog renders the .load() function to the directory it was called from

Comment: `.dialog()` doesn't get called until after `.load()` returns, so it can't have any effect on it.

Comment: Is the above code in a separate `.js` file from the one that uses it? AJAX URLs are interpreted relative to the page that performs tha AJAX call, not the `.js` file that the function was loaded from.

Comment: I updated my above question to be more specific to where files were located and what was declared in each file.

Comment: Correct the path being used. That is the only way to solve this problem. The path needs to be either absolute, or relative to the original page opened.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're loading the file from `forms/UserControls/ucEasyFill.ascx`, you need to go up a level to get into `forms/EasyFill`. So it should be:

```
MODAL_SEARCH_WINDOW = $("#modalSearchWindow").load('../EasyFill/Search.aspx').dialog({
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the issue.  The issue isn't that the EasyFill/Search.aspx page isn't getting loaded, the issue is that when i try to submit form controls on that page, they are looking for forms/search.aspx not easyfill/search.aspx like it should be, thank you for all your help BTW

Comment: Then fix the path in `action=...` in the form. It has to be relative to the page that you're loading into, not relative to where you're loading from.